# mysqli and field types

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch, types

I'd like to know if there is a simple way to fetch data from mysql tables with "correct" data types? What i mean, if field type is for example INT or SMALLINT is it possible to pass those types directly to PHP as integers?

I did some searching and found mysqli_fetch_fields, but for SMALLIT type is 2, for INT 3 and so on. It could be done that way, but it looks rather clumsy workaround. Is there any better way?

I'm using PHP and mysqli.

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you find a listing of which types were what values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to build your own database handler on top of the mysqli calls that does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, SurfaceArea from Country ORDER BY Name LIMIT 5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* Get field information for column 'SurfaceArea' */
    $finfo = $result->fetch_field_direct(1);

    printf("Name:     %s\n", $finfo->name);
    printf("Table:    %s\n", $finfo->table);
    printf("max. Len: %d\n", $finfo->max_length);
    printf("Flags:    %d\n", $finfo->flags);
    printf("Type:     %d\n", $finfo->type);

    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE table_name = 'yourtablename replace your table name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'tablecolumnname replace your table column name';
```

Use this before run your main query and after when you get your datatype then execute your operation.